# BundleConfig retuns error on trying to minify @keyframes

Tags: sass, css-animations, bundling-and-minification

I have scss scripts which use keyframes.

The BundleConfig then returns error on trying to minify the resulting css:

```
Minification failed. Returning unminified contents.
(8,9984): run-time error CSS1019: Unexpected token, found '}'
```

This is due to these two lines:

```
@-webkit-keyframes adjust-hue {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

@keyframes adjust-hue {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

How to fix it so the minification works?

Comment: Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by doing all bundling and minifying in webpack, then bundling only ready minified css files in BundleConfig. And this worked without producing the error.